# Is there any differences between ubuntu commands and ubuntu mate commands

Tags: command-line, mate

i have a low end PC and i want to install in it ubuntu to learn linux commands so i am wondering if there is any problem or difference between ubuntu-mate and ubuntu commands

Comment: This question is unclear. The primary difference between Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu-MATE is the desktop (Ubuntu uses Unity 7 for 16.04 & GNOME by default for 18.04, 20.04 & 20.10; but you didn't give release details so direct comparison cannot be made, and Ubuntu-MATE uses MATE for all releases).  They are both on the same Ubuntu base system, so using the base system is identical. Also what is a low-end PC?  I'm using a 2009 dell & running *hirsute* and can use any... Use of GUI will differ (ie. commands that operate GUI), but you're not clear on what 'commands' you're asking about

Answer (score 1):

Aside from some differences in the `gsettings` command, command line wise you're looking at no real difference (obviously not counting commands to launch graphical applications).

Comment: okay thanks that was helpful